# Change Data layout in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel data taken from vendor.
I want to change the format of layout so that it would be easier for me to ingest this data to database such as (Postgre / Mysql)

[image]

There are thousands of file in this format as one file contain information of only sales in one date.

Is there a better or fast way to convert this data or is creating VBA the only way?

Comment: You could try to unpivot the data via powerquery - not sure if that works

Answer (score 0):

We could definitely do this in VBA!
On the other hand, why bother when it can easily be accomplished with excel formulas?

My assumptions:

- You're dealing with data of variable sizes (number of regions and items)
- Cells you show as merged are merged on the actual data.
- I set this up to work with a max data range of row 100, but easy to change that.

**Step 1)**
Identify how many regions and items we have:

- `=COUNTA($D$4:$K$4)` (Regions)
  [image: CountA]
- `=COUNTA($C$6:$C$100)` (Items)
  [image: countaitems]

**Step 2)** List Items, repeating for number of regions.

- Use local line numbers rather than worksheet row numbers to make this more portable.
  To make it repeat, we're going to divide line# by total regions, roundup, then index items using that. Don't forget error handling to identify when to stop listing items. From now on, all the rest of our formulas will have a `If( *item column* <> "", *show stuff* , *don't show stuff* )` . We can gloss over that in future steps.
- `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$6:$C$100,MATCH(ROUNDUP(M5/$P$1,0),$B$6:$B$100,0)),"")`
  [image: itemlisting]

**Step 3)** Date is super easy:

- Just pull the same date for each: `=IF($O5<>"",$C$2,"")`

**Step 4)** We're going to use the `Mod()` function to create a cyclic action with our regions.

- It took me a while to play with the formula... so don't ask me what all the adjustments(translation and scaling) are for, just trust it works. `=IF($O5<>"",INDEX($D$4:$K$4,2*(MOD($M5-1,$P$1)+1)-1),"")`
  [image: Regions]

**Step 5)** "Quantity" and "Price" are the same formula, except "Price" has an extra "+1"

- Quantity = `=IFERROR(INDEX($D$6:$K$100,MATCH($O5,$C$6:$C$100,0),MATCH($P5,$D$4:$K$4,0)),"")`
- Price = `=IFERROR(INDEX($D$6:$K$100,MATCH($O5,$C$6:$C$100,0),MATCH($P5,$D$4:$K$4,0)+1),"")`
  [image: Quantity]

**FINAL PRODUCT:**

[image: final]